# При нажатии кнопки воспроизвести получаю ошибку E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

При нажатии кнопки воспроизвести или остановить получаю ошибку, это на телефоне, на эмуляторе ошибки нету.

E/MediaPlayer: pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0x7f70e1e000)
               error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button  b_Play;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
boolean prepareAsync = false;
boolean prepare = false;
boolean started = false;
boolean play = true;

String stream = "http://air.radiorecord.ru:8102/rus_320";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b_Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    b_Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (started) {
              mediaPlayer.start();
                b_Play.setText("PLAY");
            } else {
                started = true;
                started = false;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                b_Play.setText("PAUSE");
            }
         }
    });

}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            prepareAsync = true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          return prepareAsync;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            mediaPlayer.start();


    }

}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы код увидеть.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
started = true;
started = false;
```

При повторном нажатии на паузу у вас эта ошибка, т.к. плейер уже в состоянии паузы.

Вообще, перед вызовом паузы проверяйте, играет ли у вас плейер:

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}
```

Если переделать ваш код, то:

Во-первых, у вас неправильно написан `PlayerTask`, вы используете `prepareAsync`, но не задаёте обработчик. К моменту вызова `onPostExecute` у вас всё ещё может быть не готов плейер.

Во-вторых, `AsyncTask` не нужен.

Весь ваш код можно переделать так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button  b_Play;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean prepared = false;

    String stream = "http://air.radiorecord.ru:8102/rus_320";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b_Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        b_Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!prepared) {
                    return;
                }

                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    b_Play.setText("PLAY");
                }
                else {
                     mediaPlayer.start();
                     b_Play.setText("PAUSE");
                }
             }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        prepared = true;
        player.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Поправьте меня пожалуйста в коде.

Comment: @Михаил обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, вечером попробую. Вам большое уважение.

Comment: Кажись ошибку устранил, но при блокировки экрана или при переворачивании телефона приложение перестает работать, трек не играет.

Comment: @Михаил это другая проблема. Про неё лучше отдельный вопрос задать, она связана с тем, что при повороте и блокировке пересоздаётся `Activity`.

Comment: Если не трудно, можете помочь с данным вопросом

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872227/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-url-prepared-android-studio

Comment: @Михаил отметьте этот вопрос как принятый. Другой вопрос завтра посмотрю.

Comment: Подскажите, как сделать ответ принятым?

Comment: @Михаил галочку нажать в том же месте, где можно голосовать за ответ.