# Как добавить несколько URL prepared

Tags: java, android

Коллеги, пытаюсь добавить еще одну ссылку на радио с инета, сейчас есть кнопка которая воспроизводит аудио-поток, хочу добавить еще одну кнопку которая будет воспроизводит другой канал,на данный момент у меня таким образом работает:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button  b_Play;
    Button  kiss_fm;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    boolean prepared = false;
    boolean started = false;
    boolean play = true;

    String stream = "http://air.radiorecord.ru:8102/rus_320";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b_Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
        kiss_fm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kiss_fm);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        b_Play.setEnabled(false);
        b_Play.setText("LOADING");
        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);


        b_Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (started) {
                    started = false;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    b_Play.setText("PLAY");
                } else {
                    started = true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    b_Play.setText("PAUSE");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            b_Play.setEnabled(true);
            b_Play.setText("PLAY");

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (started) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (started) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (prepared) {
            mediaPlayer.release();

        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Полный код в вопрос добавьте.

Comment: Полный код добавил.

Comment: Коллеги, вопрос еще актуален, если не сложно подскажите пож.

Comment: Тут слишком много кода писать, на это, лично у меня времени совсем нет. Я могу написать ответ по поводу логики и шагов, которые вам надо сделать, но не сам код.

Comment: Если можно опишите по шагам, может знаете литературу какую-то.